# C# While loop with Multiple ||(Or) Statements not working

Tags: c#, while-loop, or-operator

I have the following C# Code

```cs
int amount_guesses = 2;
int c_answer = 4;
int u_answer = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Guessing Game");
Console.WriteLine("*Hint:The number is between 1 and 5");
Console.WriteLine("*Hint:You only get 2 guesses");

while (u_answer != c_answer || amount_guesses != 0)
{
    u_answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    amount_guesses = amount_guesses-1;
    if (u_answer == c_answer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Well Done that is the Correct Number");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong Number!Try again.You have {0} trys left", amount_guesses);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close");
Console.ReadLine();
```

But it's not jumping out of the loop when the requirements in the `while` statement are not met.
I also tried

```cs
while ((u_answer != c_answer) || (amount_guesses != 0))
```

But it's still not working, I ended changing the logic to this:

```cs
int amount_guesses = 2;
int c_answer = 4;
int u_answer = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Guessing Game");
Console.WriteLine("*Hint:The number is between 1 and 5");
Console.WriteLine("*Hint:You only get 2 guesses");

while (u_answer != c_answer && amount_guesses != 0)
{
    u_answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    amount_guesses = amount_guesses-1;
    if (u_answer == c_answer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Well Done that is the Correct Number");
        amount_guesses = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong Number!Try again.You have {0} trys left", amount_guesses);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close");
Console.ReadLine();
```

That works fine, but I wanted to know why my code at the top where I use `||` does not work?

Comment: It's the same difference between "or" (`||`) and "and" (`&&`) in any language (*I want this OR that to be true* **versus** *I want this AND that to be true*). Besides that, your title mentions "multiple OR statements" but you only have one OR statement in your body

Comment: @Rafalon Sorry about the Typo on the Title,

Answer (score 1):

A `while` loop **continues** as long as its condition is met. In your case, you want to continue loop as long as the player hasn't guessed the number and has guesses left. You should use an `&&` (logical AND) condition, not an `||`:

```
while (u_answer != c_answer && amount_guesses != 0)
{
    // Here ----------------^
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common(ish) issue when using negation in boolean logic. OR sounds like it should be right as it matches are English way of speaking, but actually AND is what you want.

I try to always write the condition testing for equality and then negate it, so instead of:

```
u_answer != c_answer && amount_guesses != 0
```

You can write:

```
!(u_answer == c_answer || amount_guesses == 0)
```

Which is the same condition.

Take a look at [De Morgams Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), also more easily remembered as

> Break the line, change the sign